# Kafka timeout exception even though the linger.ms is 0

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

In the Spring + Kafka application, `batch.size` is the default value 16384, and `linger.ms=0`. So I think when a message is created, it will imedeately sent to the broker, because 0 linger. But while running, it still get the exception sometimes.

`org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for cn-mcd-pos-promotion-3: 30033 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time`

Most of the time, the producer is OK. Sometimes it gets this excpetion. What werid is, that all the exceptions is related with  `cn-mcd-pos-promotion-3`.

1. What may cause this timeout even though the linger.ms is 0?
2. What is **-3** meaning in `cn-mcd-pos-promotion-3`?

PS: The config of producer.

````
    bootstrap.servers = [wqdcsrv3078.cn.infra:9093, wqdcsrv3079.cn.infra:9093, wqdcsrv3080.cn.infra:9095]
    buffer.memory = 33554432
    client.id = mcd.client
    compression.type = none
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    enable.idempotence = false
    interceptor.classes = null
    key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
    linger.ms = 0
    max.block.ms = 60000
    max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
    max.request.size = 1048576
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retries = 0
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.jaas.config = [hidden]
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.mechanism = SCRAM-SHA-256
    security.protocol = SASL_PLAINTEXT
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
    transactional.id = null
    value.serializer = class org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer```

Could anyone help? Thanks.
````

Comment: please share complete stack trace with max.block.ms and max.in.flight.requests.per.connection value.

Comment: The full config is added.